# how to callback in celery but not block the process

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

Now I have some big tasks, and all of them made of some small tasks,I put them into a broker,and when all small tasks of one big task is finished,I will need a callback to deal with the results of these small tasks
I know celery have the primitive chord can do it if only I have one big task,but I have many
so,if I write like:

```
chord([task11.s(),task12.s()])(mycallback.s()).get()
chord([task21.s(),task22.s()])(mycallback.s()).get()
```

the second line won't start until the first line is finished,but in this way,some workers would be idol for a long time,which is not good,
so is there some in way in celery that can callback when certain condition happens,but not block the process?

==============================================

apply_async works!@Gigapalmer, thank you for help

Comment: It's not clear to me what you can parallelize and what not.

Comment: for example,I have a list of username,and a lot of websites,I want to check is the username is registed in these websites,and then use a callback function to do some statics of these results,now I can use chord to parallelize the check function of every website,if i just enter one username,but there are a lot of usernams,
if i write the code like before,the second usersname won't start until the first if finished,but since some website already finished for the first one,I wish to use the worker for the second one

Comment: I've used celery a while back, the `get()` is synchronous and the `apply_async()` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linking the async methods so that when one finishes you call the next one in chain with apply_async and the required parameters that will technically create a new job (should be on a different queue).